Can including too many continuous variables in Little's MCAR result in Type 1 error?
When examining missing data at the individual item level (before computing scale scores), my missing data ranges from 0% - 1.7% for each individual item.
Is there a threshold at the individual item level for when I need to check whether the data is missing at random (e.g., Little’s MCAR). I have heard and read utterings of 5%, but I am unclear if they mean 5% missing for each individual item, or for the total number of items in the entire data set, or at the computed scale score level.
Out of interest’s sake, I ran Little’s MCAR on my individual questionnaire items and the test was significant, meaning that my data is MNAR. However, this seems strange to me, given that the proportion of missing data is so low within each individual item (I have a sample size of 299 participants). Is it possible that the Little’s test is not valid, given the low level of missing data? I have approximately 230 items x 299 participants. Is this a test I should even run with this level of missingness? or with this many items all at once?
When visually examining the missing data, there is no apparent pattern, the missing data is sporadic and seemingly random. It feels strange that the data would be MNAR.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
